# Reverse Interger with recursion

Tags: javascript, reverse

I am not able to find why this code is not giving proper result.for Exp:- if i provide that num as 132 then rev it should be 231.
it is not giving the expected.

```js
function reverse(num, rev) {
    if (num != 0) {
        let mod = num % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + mod;
        num = Math.floor(num / 10);
        console.log(num, rev);
        reverse(num, rev);
    }
    return rev;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a small change, you need to return the `reverse(num, rev)` inside the if condition

```js
function reverse(num, rev = 0) {
    if (num != 0) {
        const mod = num % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + mod;
        num = Math.floor(num / 10);

        return reverse(num, rev);
    }
    return rev;
}

console.log(reverse(1234))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your math and recursive function approach (fixed by Abito Prakash) is good. Here is a solution using a string split and array reverse approach, which is likely faster with large numbers:

```js
function reverse(num) {
  return parseInt(num.toString().split('').reverse().join(''), 10);
}
console.log(132, '=>', reverse(132));
console.log(1234, '=>', reverse(1234));
console.log(1234567890123456, '=>', reverse(1234567890123456));
```

Output:

```
132 => 231
1234 => 4321
1234567890123456 => 6543210987654321
```